# Change pnumwidth locally for picture / table, redefine it variably or colorbox pagenumbers

Tags: table-of-contents, formatting, page-numbering, tocloft

I'm trying to format my thesis and have a problem because of my very long appendix (which is numbered in roman). The page numbers at the end of the document exceed the defined `pnumwidth` . I know that I can change this to a bigger length, but that would imply lot of whitespace for the whole `toc`, `lof` and `lot`.

My current solution is, that I keep the `pnumwidth`, which is specified by the university-template, for the general toc at the beginning at the thesis. Before setting the `toc` for the appendix, I increased the `pnumwidth` via

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\@pnumwidth}{3em}% default is 1.55em
\makeatother
```

which works fine. But I have still the problem in my `lof` and `lot`, where the long roman numbers protrude into the dotfilled area...

I recreated this in a MWE. Is there a possibility to redefine pnumwidth **locally**, just for the figure / table, where it is necessary?

Another idea would be, to create a white box in the background of the pagenumbers, so that the dotfilled area is covered up in these cases. But I couldn't figure out, how to do that...

I appreciate any help, thanks a lot!!

```
\documentclass[listof=totocnumbered,a4paper,ngerman]{scrartcl} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[titles]{tocloft} 

\cftsetpnumwidth{0.5cm}

\renewcommand{\cftsecdotsep}{\cftdotsep}
\renewcommand{\cftsecleader}{\normalfont\cftdotfill{\cftsecdotsep}}

\begin{document}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\cftdotsep}{0.5} % Einstellung der Punktabstände im VZ
\makeatother

\newpage
\begin{figure}[!htbp]%
\caption{Picture in main document}%
\end{figure}%
\newcommand*{\thesectionwas}{}
\let\thesectionwas\thesection
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\Roman{section}}
\setcounter{section}{0}

\listoffigures % Abb-VZ
\newpage
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\Roman{section}}
\setcounter{section}{3}
\pagenumbering{Roman}
\setcounter{page}{31}

\begin{appendix}
\refstepcounter{section}
\section{Appendix Section}
\begin{figure}[!htbp]%
\caption{Picture in Appendix}%
\end{figure}%
\end{appendix}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try putting

```
\addtocontents{lof}{\protect\cftsetpnumwidth{1.5cm}}
```

before the first figure in the appendix. I haven't checked but in a full document with ToC, LoF and LoT this might affect other lists.

BTW when I run your MWE I get a warning about the use of `\begin{appendix}`.

Comment: **Thanks a lot!** This works perfectly! I changed it before the specific figures/tables in `lof` and `lot` and then back to 1.55em afterwards. Might not be the sleekest solution, but works nevertheless.